# Is there a way to get locale from country or timezone?

Tags: python, timezone, locale

I was programming a program in Python, where I need to output date as per user's locale:

1. Get a list of timezones in a country specified as per user input (did that using pytz)
2. Get the locale of the user (which I am unable to figure out how to do)

Is there a way to get locale from county/timezone or some other method needs to be followed?

Or do I need to get the locale input from user itself?

**EDIT**

The program is to be a web-app. The user can provide me his country. But does he have to explicitly provide me the locale also or can I get it from his timezone/country?

Comment: http://docs.python.org/library/locale#locale.nl_langinfo ?

Answer (score 10):

"Locale" is a country + language pair.

You have country + timezone. But no info about the language.

I don't think it's possible to convert country + timezone into a single 'correct' locale... in countries with multiple languages there is not a 1:1 relation between language and timezone.

The closest I can see is to use [Babel](http://babel.pocoo.org/docs/):

```
from babel import Locale
Locale.parse('und_BR')  # 'und' here means unknown language, BR is country
>>> Locale('pt', territory='BR')
```

This gives you a single 'most likely' (or default) locale for the country. To handle the languages *properly* you need to ask the user their preferred language.